# Oracle SQL, How do you compare a timestamp and take the data point before it?

Tags: oracle, timestamp

I have two tables. The parts of the table I care about look more or less like this.

```
CAUSEDATE                           |
____________________________________|
ID |   Timestamp                    |    
1  |  01-JAN-15 07.00.01.163000000  |
2  |  01-JAN-15 07.00.30.023000000  |
3  |  01-JAN-15 07.01.01.293000000  |
5  |  01-JAN-15 07.01.11.153000000  |
6  |  01-JAN-15 07.02.01.523000000  |


EVENTS                                             |
___________________________________________________|
ID   |   Timestamp                    |    INFO    |
101  |  01-JAN-15 07.00.01.123000000  |    Ker     |
102  |  01-JAN-15 07.00.01.233000000  |    Bal     |
103  |  01-JAN-15 07.00.01.323000000  |    Spa     |
105  |  01-JAN-15 07.00.01.553000000  |    CeP     |
106  |  01-JAN-15 07.00.01.633000000  |    rog     |
```

I want to match the timestamp in EVENTS to the timestamp in CAUSEDATE, so that when I pull ID = 1 from CAUSEDATE by its timestamp, It'll match with ID 101 in CAUSEDATE, but not any of the ones that take place afterwards within the same second. I'm only interested in the first result, and not the ones afterwards.

It's pretty variable whether "EVENTS" registers a millisecond after, or ten milliseconds, or sometimes a hundred, And in some cases it can be more then second. So what I'm looking for is a solution that looks at the timestamp in CAUSEDATE, then looks what timestamp in EVENTS takes place right before it (so it would presumably be the event that triggered the "Cause").

I've tried using `TRUNC(CAUSEDATE.Timestamp, 'MI') = TRUNC(EVENTS.Timestamp, 'MI')` but this is way too granular, and will return too much irrelevant information. There's no option to use 'SS' and even then, that wouldn't grab the data I need if it's entered a little late. Like, when it's comparing 01.993000000 with 02.006000000.

How can I retrieve the instance from EVENTS.info that is the first one before the timestamp in CAUSEDATE? So, it would give me back "Ker" as the cause of ID=1, and not "Bal"

I'm sorry for the lengthy explanation. I hope I have made my problem clear enough.

EDIT: Nearly forgot an important part.

I've thought of converting the timestamps to floats.

What I did, was use the following function

```
create or replace FUNCTION oracle_to_unix
(
in_date IN DATE)
RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
RETURN (in_date -TO_DATE('19700101','yyyymmdd'))*86400 - TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(TZ_OFFSET(sessiontimezone),1,3))*3600;
END;
```

But this only finds the events that happen to synch up perfectly with the cause time. I also want the ones that weren't logged at the perfect same time.

Comment: Why is this tagged MySQL and Oracle?  Which database are you actually using?

Comment: If this is oracle please remove the mysql tag and also post your best attempt.

Comment: Oops. Misclicked and entered both tags. I'm using Oracle. I'll edit accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, then ...

```
select *
from   events e1
join   causes c on (e1.timestamp = (select max(timestamp)
                                      from events e2
                                     where e2.timestamp < c.timestamp))
```

Comment: I've tried this, but it gives me ORA-00907: Missing right parenthesis. I've checked, there's no parenthesis missing in my script.

Comment: I have implemented it like this:

   `join substr(act.prodsteppath,3,10) on (act.date_ = select max(date_) 
                                              from act.date_ act2
                                              where act2.date_ < d.causedat) as "Cause",`

However, this always gives me a missing parenthesis or an "invalid SQL statement" message no matter what I do.

Comment: "join substr(act.prodsteppath,3,10)" ... you have to join to a table/CTE/view/subquery, not an expression.

Comment: As far as I understand "act" is a CTE, a union of all actions that take place, that is to say, it is a number of selections and unions that i'm trying to pluck the right events out of. Using just `join act.prodsteppath on` gives me a "Missing Expression" error now.

Comment: You join to ACT, and then specify which columns/expressions to join using the ON clause.

Comment: Well, it awnsers my question, but it seems my circumstances are much more complex then I previously assumed. Will accept the awnser as fitting to the question i posed.